# CiviMail - KC Finder Cannot Upload Images in CiviCRM 4.6.8

Tags: civimail

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Wordpress 4.3.1. When using composing an HTML message template, I am unable to upload images into the email, using KC finder. I get these warnings:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/crm/wp-content/plugins/every-calendar-1/widgets/register.php
>   on line 23
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/mysite/public_html/crm/wp-content/plugins/every-calendar-1/widgets/register.php:23) in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/class/browser.php
>   on line 112
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/mysite/public_html/crm/wp-content/plugins/every-calendar-1/widgets/register.php:23) in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/class/browser.php
>   on line 113

Then when I try to upload an image, I browse for the image on my local machine and then it gives me this warning:

> Cannot write to upload folder.

Where does Civi upload images by default?
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I find this working on wp demo site wp46.demo.civicrm.org. Can you recheck if you have write permission set for the upload folder ?

Comment: Thanks, I can check the write permissions, but how do I know which is the upload folder?